# NSSharingService.perform() with Send To Photos

Tags: swift, macos, share, photo

On MacOS (catalyst app, but AppKit bundle) I am creating Share submenu in main app menu "on fly" from menu delegate like this:

```
func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {

    self.provider = NSItemProvider(contentsOf: url)! //url points to existing temporary file of type .png
    
    menu.removeAllItems()
    let srvcs = NSSharingService.sharingServices(forItems: [self.provider!])
    for srv in srvcs {
        let it = NSMenuItem(title: srv.menuItemTitle, action: #selector(openSharingService), keyEquivalent: "")
        it.image = srv.image
        it.representedObject = srv
        it.target = self
        
        menu.addItem(it)
    }
}
@objc private func openSharingService(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let service = (sender.representedObject as! NSSharingService)
    service.perform(withItems: [self.provider!])
}
```

It works well for any share type, except for Send To Photos. With Send To Photos, I am getting this error in console:

```
2021-10-27 08:59:02.042220+0200 Calculator2[14383:7732689] [xpc.exceptions] <NSXPCConnection: 0x6000008470c0> connection to service on pid 14388 named com.apple.share.System.add-to-iphoto.apple-extension-service: Exception caught during decoding of received selector _completeRequestReturningItems:forExtensionContextWithUUID:completion:, dropping incoming message.
Exception: Exception while decoding argument 0 (#2 of invocation):
Exception: value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSURL (0x7fff801889e8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]'. Allowed classes are '{(
    "NSDate (0x7fff80188600) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "NSString (0x7fff801ba8d0) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]",
    "NSNumber (0x7fff801ba3a8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework]",
    "NSData (0x7fff801885d8) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "NSDictionary (0x7fff80188650) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]",
    "NSArray (0x7fff80188510) [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework]"
)}'.
```

Photos app is opened and image is added to it, but my app recieves the above error and its menus are all grayed out until restarted. Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT: I tried to call service like this (passing NSImage):

```
            self.provider!.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.png", completionHandler: {(data, error) in
                let img = NSImage(data: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    service.perform(withItems: [img])
                }
           })
```

... and it fails with exactly the same error. Again complaining against NSURL, even if I don't pass NSURL at all.

Comment: The error says it all.

Comment: @ElTomato But I don't understand it. NSSharingService.sharingServices(forItems: [self.provider!]) offered Send To Photos as service for this.provider, but then fails on using it? And is it normal that Send To Photos can't be called on png image? When it in fact works (Photos app really adds the image), but also breaks my app?

Comment: Have you ever heard of a practice called 'unwrapping an optional variable' in Swift?

Comment: @ElTomato I have, but can you tell me where exactly do you see the error?

Comment: Have you tried an exception breakpoint?

Comment: @Willeke Just now, but it doesn't help. It breaks in this: libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw , and nothing on stack in the thread is my code.

Comment: I don't know what the correct solution is, but I can shed some light on the error. When you call `NSSharingService.sharingServices(forItems: [self.provider!])`, you're getting back an `NSSharingService`. You would expect that each returned `NSSharingService` would be able to share the `NSItemProvider` that you gave, but it appears to not be the case. In attempting to `NSSharingService.perform(withItems:)`, you're calling a library function which sends an XPC message to `com.apple.share.System.add-to-iphoto.apple-extension-service`. As you can see, it didn't expect an `NSURL` in the msg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could not fing the error, but I managed to make workaround. I added folloowing code to my func openSharingService(), in order to recognize Add to Photos and handle it in a different way:

```
if ( (service == NSSharingService(named: .addToIPhoto)) && (self.provider!.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.png")) ) {
        self.provider!.loadObject(ofClass: NSURL.self, completionHandler: {(val, error) in
            //print(val)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let u = val as! NSURL
                self.photosHandler(u)
                NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication("Photos")
            }
        })
    }
```

self.photosHandler is a callback filled from my catalyst bundle of app, that adds photo using PHPhotoLibrary:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .addOnly, handler: self.OnAuthorizationDone)
```

(OnAuthorizationDone() also has to be implemented, using `PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges()` and `PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage()` )